# Are “this” and “next” demonstrative determiners?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, determiners, syntactic-analysis, demonstratives

**Question 1:** In the following, is *this* a **demonstrative determiner**:

> I will go to the store this week.

**Question 2:** If so, then what class is *next* in the following:

> I will go to the store next week.

**Question 3:** It seems that both serve the same grammatical syntax and function here; are they therefore classified the same? (If not, why not?)

Comment: The usual dictionaries (though [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/next) seems to have second thoughts) class 'next' in this usage as an 'adjective'. I'm with you in considering it functions as a determiner here, and I'd say a demonstrative determiner (pointing out which one). 'Last' used this way is similar; 'next ___ but one' seems a complex (and split) example.

Comment: _This, that, these, those_ are demonstrative. _Next_ is originally a locative (the superlative in _nigh, near, next_), but is frequently used metaphorically of time in sequence of events (_The next speaker is Ms. Hobbs_). Like all superlatives, and all demonstratives, it's definite, so there's lots of meaning overlap, but the demonstrative pronouns have their own paradigm and relate to other definite `TH`-words like _the, thence, thither, thus, then,_ and _there_.

Comment: @John Lawler Are you saying here 'Not an adjective, but not a fully-paid-up member of any other known club'?

Comment: _This_ is not an adjective but a determiner. _Next_ is an adjective and can co-occur with determiners. They're both definite. They both quantify and determine, but they don't do it the same way. You can't expect a great deal from syntactic category labels; they're rarely specific enough to be useful in every case.

Comment: @John Lawler Calling 'next' an adjective certainly messes up my concepts of adjectives as words saying something further about the intrinsic nature of the noun's referent, and of words 'serv[ing] to express the reference of th[e] noun or noun phrase in the [relevant] context' (Wikipedia) being determiners. I know you weight syntactic and perhaps morphological diagnostics more than I like to.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well, it's not a typical adjective, that's for sure. More like an adjective with superpowers, like _worth_, which (if it is an adjective) is a transitive adjective, because it can come with a measure phrase, like _worth $300_. But it's not likely that any semantic definition of a syntactic phenomenon will survive in any case, since they're backwards; it's true that persons, places, and things are always represented by nouns, but it's false that nouns always represent persons, places, and things. Structure determines structural classes, meaning determines semantic classes.

Comment: The authors of the Longman Grammar call it, along with *same* and *other*, a ‘semi-determiner’.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why do you offer up valid answers via comments so frequently? I feel like you're perhaps misusing the comment section where an actual answer belongs.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can *short* work like a transitive adjective when you're short a dollar? What if you're missing a dollar? Surely that one is just a verb but how is it different? Is this how things like *during* eventually develop into prepositions?

Comment: @tchrist _Miss, lack, be without, not have,_ and _be short_ all take complements, as do _-ing_ predicates like _be missing_ and _be lacking_. But they don't mean the same things. Consider _He's missing a finger on his left hand_ versus _He lacks a finger on his left hand_ versus _He doesn't have a finger on his left hand._ Try these with other numbers. There was a question about this on my PhD qualifying exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-answer.  The various answers given don't seem to be complete.  The best I can tell regarding the answer of this is "it's a bit complicated" and I refer the interested reader to look at the main comments for discussion.  Particularly, John Lawler's comment:

> You can't expect a great deal from syntactic category labels; they're rarely specific enough to be useful in every case.

Answer (score 2):

*Demonstrative determiner* is not exactly a syntactic category; *determiner* is a syntactic category, but *demonstrative* is basically an etymological+semantic grouping consisting of *this*, *that*, *these*, and *those*.

So although *next* is a determiner in some cases, it is never a "demonstrative determiner".

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> *This, that, these, those* are demonstrative. *Next* is originally a locative (the superlative in *nigh, near, next*), but is frequently used metaphorically of time in sequence of events (*The next speaker is Ms. Hobbs*). Like all superlatives, and all demonstratives, it's definite, so there's lots of meaning overlap, but the demonstrative pronouns have their own paradigm and relate to other definite `TH`-words like *the, thence, thither, thus, then,* and *there.*