# What part of speech is “this” in the following sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech

My friends and I are having a stupid argument about this sentence:

- Someday this pain will be useful to you.

I claim “this” in this sentence is an adjective modifying pain, but they claim it is a demonstrative pronoun in this instance. Can someone please confirm what part of speech it is? This does not seem hard to me but they seem so confident against it.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't come across the 'new' word-class 'determiner' (some grammarians insist on 'determinative'). Most grammarians say that a determiner is distinct from an adjective. In 'this pain' (/this car, lake, bad weather, little house of mine ...) 'this' is nowadays seen to have a different role from that of an adjective. It identifies the location / place in a framework of the following noun's referent, rather than describing a property inherent to the referent (small / old / red / expensive / appalling / jointly-owned ... [house]. Look up 'determiner' on Wikipedia, and here.

Comment: Don't be so stuck on black and white thinking. A thing can be many things. 'this' is acting like an adjective there. It is also somewhat pronominal (referring to a pain already mentioned/implied). To distinguish this particular use, it is called a demonstrative. So yeah, you're both right. I think it is more like an adjective than it is like a pronoun, but you both are using appropriate labels,

Comment: Does _**this**_ answer your question? [Are “this” and “next” demonstrative determiners?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164760/are-this-and-next-demonstrative-determiners)

Comment: Incidentally, what does the sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond being a demonstrative pronoun or a demonstrative adjective: how we refer to ideas and situations in English is not always about physical objects.

A deictic expression or deixis is a word or phrase (such as this, that, these, those, now, then, here) that points to the time, place, or situation in which a speaker is speaking. Deixis is expressed in English by way of personal pronouns, demonstratives, adverbs, and tense. The term's etymology comes from the Greek, meaning "pointing" or "show," and it's pronounced "DIKE-tik."

https://www.thoughtco.com/deictic-expression-deixis-1690428 [deixis](https://www.thoughtco.com/deictic-expression-deixis-1690428)

Sample sentence: Someday this pain will be useful to you.

**"this** pain" refers to the pain one person hears about from another, when they are talking to each other. Not "that pain" which was referred to at another point in time by the other speaker and which this speaker is now referring to.

Often, it is difficult for non-native speakers to grasp this usage of this/that in a discourse situation.

**This** is a difficult question. [pronoun]
**This question** is difficult. [adjective]
**That** one is easy. [adjective]
**That** is difficult. [something one person is referring to in another person's speech, pronoun]
**This** is difficult. [something being referred to by a speaker as "appropriated" by them, pronoun]

Clearly, the word *this* or *that* + a noun function as a adjectives AKA determiners whereas *this* or *that* without another noun function as stand-alone nouns.

(It really does not matter whether you call it a "demonstrative determiner" or "demonstrative adjective". It boils down to the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

**This** in “Someday this pain will be useful to you.” is a demonstrative adjective (and a determiner.)

Comment: Thank you! Love how you mentioned determiners as well

Comment: Not an adjective, according to CGEL, which far outranks OED on POS-identification.

Comment: Conventionally, grammar says This, That, These & Those are demonstrative adjectives. When they occur exactly before nouns, they are adjs., but when they function like This is the pain., That is the med., etc. they shift to pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Someday **this** pain will be useful to you*.
>
> [2] *Someday **this** will be useful to you*.

No: it's neither an adjective nor a pronoun.

In both [1] and [2] "this" is best analysed as a demonstrative determinative.

In its dependent use [1] i.e. with a following noun, its function is that of determiner.

In its independent use [2] i.e. without a following noun, its function is that of fused determiner-head.

Comment: Pullum: Many determinatives occur as fused determiner-heads,
making a whole NP (**I saw some**). This is not that.

Comment: @Lambie It's the same analysis. "This" is typically deictic with a nominal as antecedent and analysed as "this x", where it realises the fusion of determiner and head functions. For example, "The wine we had earlier was too sweet for me, but **this** is perfect", where the NP "this" is understood as "this wine", thus it is both determiner and head of the NP.